# Is it possible to control my windows PC from my iPad and without internet?

Tags: windows, networking, microsoft-word, ios, remote-control

I want to write about 60 pages of math equations and fastest way (that I know) is to use office word 2016 and use ink equation editor. It is very difficult to write a single equation using the mouse to draw the symbols. I thought maybe if I use a touch screen and maybe a pen I could achieve a fast way to write the equations. 
I know how to remote control my PC from my iPad but all the apps that allow this also need internet connection. 
Is there a way to control my PC but without internet connection since my internet speed is very low and not stable right now. 
I thought maybe by connecting both devices to the same router and creating a homegroup. Like the app SHAREit where you can send files easily when both devices have the app installed and are in the same network.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23083/how-can-i-use-my-ipad-as-a-graphics-tablet and https://www.digitalartsonline.co.uk/news/creative-hardware/this-amazing-app-turns-your-ipad-pro-into-cintiq/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best step right now is to use Microsoft Remote Desktop if you have Windows 10 Pro. You mentioned that you don't have great speeds but it will still work.

To do this, first, you must get Microsoft Remote Desktop from the App Store. Make sure that Remote Desktop is enabled on your Windows PC under System Management. Then, you will need to add your PC's information into Remote Desktop on your iPad.

Another step you could take is signing into Microsoft Word and write the equations then signing in on the same account on your iPad.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I couldn't figure out how to configure this app but I used teamview which was smoother than I thought. But turned out even with touch screen the MS Office ink equation editor couldn't give me the results I was looking for. I thought I could achieve something similar to this youtube video but this needs very good skills and/or some special input device. youtube.com/watch?v=x3o2WJ5rHhU
I couldn't write smooth characters which is the main cause why MS word failed.

Answer (score 0):

As Tutors says, you can use Microsoft Remote Desktop.

The detailed steps are as follows:

1.Create a local area network

Find a router and the PC device is connected to the router with a network cable.

Connect the router's infinite network with an iPad.

2.Download and install Microsoft Remote Desktop in the app store.

3.Find your account in the control panel, set your password.

4.Open the network and share center, and then tap the network you're connected to.

5.Change automatic IP acquisition to a fixed IP address(the address of your router).

6.Open the Microsoft Remote Desktop, add the PC in the upper right corner, and the pc name is the fixed ip address just set. The username is your computer's username and password